# Can't set entity value and insert it into table because of lazyloading

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, lazy-loading, relationship

```
I have UserItem() entity.
I have Shard() entity.
I have Item() entity.
```

**Shard()** entity has method **getItem()** which gets **Item()** entity.

When I try to add data to UserItem() entity.

```
$userItem->setItem($item);
$userItem->setUser($this->websiteUser);
$em->merge($userItem);
```

By using **setItem()** and **setUser()** methods.

I can't do it because in **setItem($item)**

parameter **$item** has class of

```
Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Item
```

When it only accepts

```
AppBundle\Entity\Item
```

I get $item like that:

```
$item = $em->getRepository(Item::class)->find($shards[$i]->getItem()->getId());
```

**$shards** is an array with **Shard()** entities.

All relationships in Entities are defined correctly.

How can I overcome this situation?

I know that I get proxies because of lazyloading.

Comment: Should I just add fetch="EAGER" to my relationship in Doctrine?

Comment: Why exactly is the proxy class a problem? In simple use cases the proxy classes should not cause any issues. Can you show the whole `UserItem` class?

Comment: http://codepad.org/Xc8K1yxn

Comment: Did you run your code? Do you get any errors? Usually the proxy classes aren't a problem (unless you get actual errors because of them).

Comment: Yes I have ran my code without any issues.
The problem is setUser() expects entity class without lazyloaded entity...

The only way I managed to solve this at this time by disabling lazyloading in Shard() entity's $item property.

Otherwise it just cant get any data and tries to insert NULL into table's column, while my column is NOT NULL. Now it works, but only by setting 
fetch = "EAGER"..

Comment: You have something else going on.  You should not need EAGER for this and it will probably bite you later.  However, I don't follow your explanation at all and I don't see the need for $em->merge.  Maybe try posting actual code?

Comment: The Doctrine entity proxies extends from the original entity class, so type-hinting an argument with `AppBundle\Entity\Item $item` should allow instance of `Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\Item`.

Comment: Yeah, I'll dig into the problem by myself, something is causing it.

Comment: can you double check your imports ?

Comment: As pointed @zizoujab you maybe included with `use` keyword doctrine proxy class, I did this mistake sometimes ^^